# Lip balm looking feminine on man lip

Tags: personal-care

I noticed that lip balm is looking like feminine to me. I thought it happened cause I used too much lipbalm. But later noticed it still looks like feminine when I apply a little lip balm. Is it possible to apply it without looking too feminine? I think it is looking like that for my dark skin, isn't it?

[image]

Does it really look like a lipstick?

Comment: Are you sure you used lip balm and not lipstick?

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar that question makes me think.... But it was written lip balm on the body.... I asked seller before buying "Is it for men also?" He replied,"anyone can use it. Both boys and girls"

Comment: haha we're in 2022 man. The seller probably meant that anyone is free to use whatever they want. So I'm 99% sure you actually used lipstick by mistake. All good, just buy the correct product and you should be fine. Actual lip balm doesn't show on the lips.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar are you completely sure? https://www.quora.com/Is-it-girly-for-men-to-wear-a-red-colored-lip-balm?share=1 https://www.amazon.com/pink-lip-balm/s?k=pink+lip+balm

Comment: One of my sister suggested me to buy a product (I don't know what that is called, can't remember the name, since I wasn't interested that moment). She told me that, that product will make my lip pink and moisturize it also. I didn't buy that cause that will cost me extra shipping charge (150tk for 30tk's product).

Comment: Well of course there are all kinds, I meant classic lip balm, like the one linked in my answer, such brand should not have any color. About what your sister suggested can't know, but figure she would like seeing you with pink lips, hence such suggestion. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar does colorless lip balm has smell?

Comment: I have strawberry lip balm that I sometimes use, it does not color my lips but yes it does have a sweet smell. My classic lip balm, that I use more often, has no smell.

Comment: You could dab a small amount of vaseline on your lips if they are dry or chapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you are using brands with special tastes or color, however there are plenty of brands that offer lip balm for dry lips that is totally transparent.

For example [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0153GPM62) (Labello), it's a brand I'm using sometimes and it doesn't show at all.

Comment: I wanted pink type lip balm. But pink+black=dark red (that's what I can see happening). I also wonder if its only looking to me cause recently a girl told me that I have changed and looking more beautiful than before... But I worry I can't see any brand name on my lip balm :) (only Vitamin E lip balm written on the product)

Comment: @Man you're using wrong product. You should buy ordinary lip balm, no vitamins, and without color. You can go to pharmacy and ask there, it's no shame. :)